# Recursive Linq or Sql query to get topmost parent of each category in self referencing table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

e.g. If I have a table like below:-

```
    create table Categories(CategoryId int primary key,
 ParentCategoryId int foreign key references Categories(CategoryId))
```

e.g If I have the following data in my table:-

```
CategoryID  ParentCategoryId
1           2
2           3
3           4
4           NULL
5           6
6           7
7           NULL
8           9
9           NULL

Result:     

CategoryId  ParentCategoryId
1           4
2           4
3           4
4           NULL
5           7
6           7
7           NULL
8           9
9           NULL
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is a root Category's ParentCategoryId set to (NULL, it's own Category ID, something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the recursive CTE solution.  Probably more elegant and efficient?

```
WITH TopLevelParents AS (
    SELECT CategoryID, ParentCategoryID
    FROM Categories
    WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.CategoryID, ISNULL(p.ParentCategoryID, p.CategoryID) ParentCategoryID
    FROM Categories c
    JOIN TopLevelParents p ON c.ParentCategoryID = p.CategoryID
)
SELECT *
FROM TopLevelParents
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @childId int
SET @childId = 1

DECLARE @nextId int
DECLARE @currentId int

SET @nextId = @childId

WHILE (NOT (@nextId IS NULL))
BEGIN
    SET @currentId = @nextId

    SELECT @nextId = ParentCategoryId
    FROM Categories
    WHERE CategoryId = @currentId
END

SELECT @currentId AS RootCategoryId
```

In Linq you're looking at something like:

```
public int GetRootCategoryId(int childId)
{
    int? nextId = childId
    int? currentID;

    while (nextID != null)
    {
        currentID = nextID;
        nextID = (from category in db.Categories
                 where category.CategoryId = currentID
                 select category.ParentCategoryId).First();
    }

    return currentID;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... this will do one at a time, which might be inefficient in SQL if you want the whole table as originally suggested.  Still, a good approach for something of more general purpose use.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Parents (CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY, ParentCategoryID INT)
INSERT #Parents
SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT != 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET p.ParentCategoryID = c.ParentCategoryID
    FROM #Parents p
    JOIN Categories c ON p.ParentCategoryID = c.CategoryID
    WHERE c.ParentCategoryID IS NOT NULL
END
SELECT *
FROM #Parents
ORDER BY 1
DROP TABLE #Parents
```